# Invoke method(s) only conditionally

Tags: java, sonar

estoy usando sonarQube como analizador de codigo y obtengo el siguiente error :

> **Invoke method(s) only conditionally.**
>
> "Preconditions" and logging arguments should not require evaluation

Con los siguientes codigos:

```
if (specialPids.size() % 2 == 0)
{
  doSomething();
 if (tkfName.isPresent() && datName.isPresent())
  {        
    doSomething(); 
  }else{
     logger.fine(String.format("No tkf or dat collocation files found for the    program [%s]",context.getProgramId()));
  }else{
    logger.warning(String.format("The program [%s] has an invalid number of collocations files",
                               context.getProgramId()));
 }
```

La solucion que siempre he aplicado en estos casos a sido , con el String.format , pero me sigue dando el mismo error .

¿Ideas?

Comment: ¿Has probado a poner con un toString?

Comment: Tienes dos `else` para el mismo `if`. ¿¿¿¿Eso compila????

Comment: @SuperG280 No puede compilar, falta algo ahí

Comment: Que logger usas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mi me ha pasado, puedes probar con:

```
logger.fine("No tkf or dat collocation files found for the program {}", context.getProgramId());
```